# Split a large excel workbook with multiple worksheets into multiple files based on a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets with about 200000 rows. Each worksheet has a state column, and the states are common in all worksheets. I need separate files created based on the state column.

```
Eg.
Workbook1

Sheet 1
City   Code
NY    1000C
NY    1100C
NY    1200C
SF    2000C
SF    2100C
LA    3000C

Sheet 2
City   Blocks
NY      1.2
NY      2.0
LA      1.7
```

New workbook should have 2 sheets all states from each worksheet. For eg. NY should have its own workbook with 2 worksheets with only NY.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have experience with Java or Python then you could use either [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) or [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) respectively, which is probably what I would do for a complex modification of an excel workbook. Alternatively, you could just do it manually by copy/pasting rows and columns that need to be moved around.

There really isn't any quick and easy way to do something like this, unfortunately...